# After upgrading from .NET 6 to .NET 8 getting Results.Json Ambiguous call

Tags: .net-8.0

After I upgraded from .NET 6 to .NET 8, this line of code:

```
Results.Json(result.Value, null, "application/problem+json", results.StatusCode)
```

is throwing an "ambiguous call error" between

```
Results.Json(object?, JsonSerializerOptions?, string?, int?) 

Results.Json<TValue>(TValue?, JsonTypeInfo<TValue>, string?, int?)
```

In my original call, `results.Value` is an object, `results.StatusCode` is an int.

I'm assuming because I'm passing in null for 2nd param it's causing this but how do I get the same effect if I don't want to pass anything into `JsonSerializerOptions`?

Comment: You can solve the problem bt replacing `null` with `JsonSerializerOptions.Default`. Then the compiler knows which method to call.